# Why is it that during matcher execution in one of the Slices, the incoming data array is written to the state of the other slice as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

So, in my project there are 2 slices: option slices and ticket reducer. While filling in the data in the countrySelect component, I write this data to the options array, but for some reason, they are also written to the tickets array of the ticketsReducer slice.
https://github.com/Chvertko/diplom
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A809.png)

All attempts to catch why this is happening have failed, I know that I probably initially chose the wrong architecture, however, the ticket search feature works, but the fetchCountries function should not write data to the tickets array.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.